# IntelliJ IDEA Cursor moves to beginning of line when hitting Ctrl-S

Tags: intellij-idea, save, caret

The cursor in my IntelliJ code editor always returns to the beginning of the line (removing all whitespace) when I save by hitting Ctrl-S.

If I have code on that line and save then move to the next line, the cursor starts at the very beginning of the line (instead of indented to where that line of code should start).

This is very annoying as I am in the habit of manually saving often.

If relevant I am on IntelliJ 2016.3, Windows 7.

Any advice is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You can disable Strip trailing spaces on save in Settings/Editor/General. However the label explicitly says that the trailing space will not be removed on the line the caret is on, so this might be a bug in 2016.3 (I remember that it worked properly in earlier versions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I think it is a bug.
I created an issue for it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-164345
You can vote for it or comment on it.

Comment: Actually I used the settings showed in your picture on the issue ticket. It seems to have worked for me. (I did not know this option existed).